# OutOfMemoryError - through weblogic server

Tags: java

How to resolve OutOfMemoryError in weblogic server

Increase Heap size - -Xmx10G, -Xms10G
implemented SFTP instead of FTP

byte[] fileArr = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream out;

```
    StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder();

    strBuild.append(path);

    strBuild.append(fileName);
InputStream inputStr = null;

    BufferedInputStream bis = null;

    ByteBuffer buffer = null;

    ReadableByteChannel inputChannel = null;
            WritableByteChannel outputChannel = null;


    try {

        inputStr = this.sftpClient.getInputStream(strBuild.toString());

                if(READ_BUFFER_SIZE <= 0){          

                    buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
                }

                else{
                    buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(READ_BUFFER_SIZE);

                }

                bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStr);

                out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                inputChannel = Channels.newChannel(bis);

                outputChannel = Channels.newChannel(out);

                while (inputChannel.read(buffer) > 0) {
                    buffer.flip();

                    outputChannel.write(buffer);

                    buffer.compact();
                }
```

Need response in ByteArray of input file

Comment: below code throwing OutOfMemoryException while writting buffer in "outputChannel:"

 while (inputChannel.read(buffer) > 0) {
                    buffer.flip();

                    outputChannel.write(buffer);

                    buffer.compact();
                }

Comment: How big is the file you are working with?

Comment: Its more than 2 GB of file's size

Comment: From server log you see that you have increased the Heap size. In the server .out file do you read correct startup parameters?

Answer (score 1):

In your coude I don't see where you close your Streams.
Probably server keeps your open buffers.

Insert a try-with-resource (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) or close your streams in your code

Comment: I think it would be enough to just null them out, so gc triggers, but not even this was made...

Comment: Stream is closed in finally block

Comment: Is any lead on this issue... ?